# how to get a index of row after it satisfies certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing, max

a data frame of the country name in rows with corresponding medals win in summer and winter Olympics

I want in this data frame to get the country name which has a max difference in summer gold and winter gold, let's say summer gold column name is `x` and winter gold column name is `y`

all the country names are an index of rows

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to provide a sample data frame so we can help better. I think you are looking for this:

```
(df.y-df.x).idxmax()
```

And if you care only about the absolute value of difference:

```
(df.x-df.y).abs().idxmax()
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3],'y':[2,10,5]}, index=['a','b','c'])

   x   y
a  1   2
b  2  10
c  3   5

print((df.y-df.x).abs().idxmax())

b
```